# Should I use a class even for a single html element?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website design and my boss told me that usually ids are never used and classes are preferred, but he doesn't remember why. So I did some research and I found this [this](https://www.quora.com/Do-you-use-class-or-ID-more-in-HTML-Why-Which-is-easier-to-work-with-when-using-HTML-CSS-JavaScript-PHP-MySQL), but the first answer does not explain very well why ids should not be used. I thought that for an element that is used only once ids were used. If I won't use an element more than once, why should I use a class?

Comment: Depends on how the site/project is going to scale. If you think that styling is going to be used elsewhere make it a `class`. If it's 100% unique use an `ID`. Pretty much the basics of it. `ID`'s also help determine selectors for use in jQuery etc.

Comment: Id's using for unique think to do. but classes can be use multiple. better to add classes for style.

Comment: I would be careful to style using an id, just because for all practical purposes, you're styling for a single page, not for all pages.  Better at that point to have an `<table id="accessorTable" class="dataTable">` and style dataTable.   Otherwise, I have no problem using ids when I know there will be only one.

Comment: @Neil: What does styling an id have to do with the number of pages are you styling? What does it matter how many pages you have if the element with that id is consistent across all of those pages?

Comment: @BoltClock You shouldn't have 15 pages with elements with the same id.  Ideally it is in one page that gets included in many others.  Having the same id in 15 different pages seems like a bad pattern to use.  You're only creating the possibility of collision.

Comment: @Neil: I think you and I have a very different definition of "page" in that case. I'm not talking about partials or includes - I'm talking about entire documents ("pages"). An element with an id of #logo might appear in the header include only, which is then included in 15 pages - every one of those pages would have a single #logo element, and that would be just fine, provided the author knows that specific instance (in terms of HTML/CSS) of the company logo isn't going to appear anywhere other than the header.

Comment: @BoltClock Then I think we're in agreement.  I meant having separate page components using the same id might be troublesome.  Including two page components into the same page with the same id would be troublesome and therefore the practice of using the same id across multiple pages doesn't strike me as an excellent idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's related to performance issues. Even though you are using this element for a single time, I would still recommend using a `class` instead of an `id`.

Why? 'cause you may add some more classes to this element in the future. But why is this important and related to performance? Take a look at this:

> It’s a common belief that ID selectors are the fastest, but this comes
>   with a big caveat: IDs are fastest CSS selector only if they’re the
>   key selector. What’s that? Well, while you probably read selectors
>   from left to right, browsers read them from right to left.

For more details, just check this [site](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/).

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use classes. Even if it's a single element. Consider what will happen if you want to reuse the CSS for that single element in the future - it will no longer be a single element and you will have to change it to be a class.

Also IDs have additional functionality compared to classes: you can add the `#yourId` to the URL and make the browser auto-scroll to that element when you open the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to use ids or classes entirely depends on your need. Its not good to say that we should not use ids. Here are some key points.

- IDS and classes act as hook and they are required to select an element.
- Each element can have only 1 id and each page can have that id only once.
- You can use the same class on multiple elements.
- You can use multiple classes on the same element. Adding a class name
  or ID to an element does nothing to that element by default.
- **ID's have special browser functionality**. This is the "hash value" in the
  URL. If you have a URL like http://yourdomain.com#comments, the
  browser will attempt to locate the element with an ID of "comments"
  and will automatically scroll the page to show that element.
- **Javascript love id**s thats why we have **document.getElementById();**
- Jquery loves classes and its very easy to add classes on an element.

Read https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ for more

Answer (score 0):

`class` is used to classify a group of elements that can be styled together.
So if you are classifying based on any criteria as per your presentation logic, use classes.

`id` is used to identify a single element using a *unique identifier*. So if you are *uniquely identifying* an element in a page use Ids. The validations make sure its following this concept and throws an error otherwise. So as per specification and implementation there is no **reliable** way we can use `class` to uniquely identify an element. Which explains why we are having Id.

As a matter of fact, if you have no need to uniquely identify an element in your presentation, you probably don't require this feature at all.

And about performance, think of performance only when its crucial. Don't over optimise and lose readability and semantics unless performance is already affecting your page rendering.